# Deploying Multiple Node js app on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the node js code in my repository which is nothing but separate microservices. I want to deploy the application on Elastic Beanstalk. For this process, I have written a script in package.json to run two builds at a time parallelly and which would create 2 separate build folders that would contain index.js files in these directories.

1. How do I point index.js files that are in these directories in the elastic beanstalk?
2. These 2 microservices would have 2 different URL's say a.api.com and b.api.com. How do I point this microservices to different URL's.